# Paperclip deprecated method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I upgraded my rails app from `rails 2.3.14` to `rails 3.2.6`. In my model i have the following  method that is being called from my view for image editing purpose.

```
def logo_geometry(style = :original)
  @geometry ||= {}
  @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(logo.to_file(style)) # works with s3
end
```

when this method is called following error occurs.

```
undefined method `to_file' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0xd9d06e0>
```

Any suggestion to achieve the functionality of `to_file` method??

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/833

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer to my own question.

replace `logo.to_file(style)` **with** `Paperclip.io_adapters.for(logo.styles[style])`.

so method will be be like this..

```
def logo_geometry(style = :original)
  @geometry ||= {}
  @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(logo.styles[style])) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Paperclip is beginning to really annoy me now.

Comment: Yep. So when can you call this function ? On after_save, I get this : Paperclip::AbstractAdapter#path delegated to tempfile.path, but tempfile is nil: Paperclip::NilAdapter: